# How to write output continous row from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am working on `JSP` and `servlet`.
Code below works, but I want it to be more dynamic.

Here's my JSP

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <form ACTION="Servlet" method="POST">
    <body><h1>Data Mahasiswa</h1>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nama </td>
                <td>: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" /></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr><td>NIM </td>
                <td>: <input type="text" name="ID" value="" /></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Progdi </td>
                <td>: <input type="radio" name="Member" value="Not Member" />Not Member
                    <input type="radio" name="Member" value="Member" />Member
                 
                </td>  
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my Servlet

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String temp;
    private BufferedWriter writer;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String s1 = request.getParameter("Name");
    String s2 = request.getParameter("ID");
    String s3 = request.getParameter("Member");

    try{
try {
            String text = (s1 + " | " + s2 + " | " + s3);
            File file = new File("D:/write.txt");
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.write(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
  finally{  
            out.println("<h1> Data Saved <h1>");
      }  
}
```

And I'd like to make my output write.txt as below

```
Bill | 788878 | Member
Mark | 655598 | Member
Ron | 953116 | Not Member
```

Current code only works for 1 row only.

What I mean is, every re-entry input data, they would be written on next row on output txt file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for code review should be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try
`writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));`.

The extra `true` specifies that the write mode is `append`, not `over write`

> append - boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the
>   file rather than the beginning.

Comment: But, how do I make it able to write it on the next row, as I see it writes on the next column.
I've tried added "\n" on the back but it didn't work

Comment: are you in windows? if so `\n` alone won't help, you have to give `\r\n`. However you can simply give this statement `writer.newLine();`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034585/why-does-n-give-a-new-line-on-windows