# taking output 2D array in matrix form

Tags: c

I need to print out/create (.CSV format) an array of size 1940(R) by 512(C). I have a large program where this matrix is created by using different other matrices. On execution, it shows all the data in one line. I need this data in .csv or excel format to use it.

Can anybody help me what to do here?

`printf("\n")` command is working for printing on screen in matrix form, but in output file it's all in one line.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 1940; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < 512; j++ ) {
        fprintf(pFile,",%d\t ",X7[i][j]);
        //printf("%d\t ", X8[i][j]);     
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You need to write `'\n'` to the file as well.

Comment: CinCout thanks for your answer but can you please elaborate a little bit more

Comment: If you are using Windows and looking at file with Notepad, then `\n` can be not enough. Notepad uses `\r\n` as line break. Try first viewing your file in Notepad++ or something more advanced then classic Notepad. You cen find out more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034585/why-does-n-give-a-new-line-on-windows

Comment: I am using on Linux system and trying to see the data in text or Libre office writer/calc

Answer (score 3):

You need to write the "newline" to the file, not to the console.
Instead of

```
printf("\n");
```

write

```
fprintf(pFile, "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan Lechner but now it is showing in one column(all the data). I think it is putting line after every character with this command fprintf(pFile, "\n");

Comment: Thanks Stephan Lechner... I was using it wrong but now it worked, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your example you use:

```
fprintf(pFile,",%d\t ",X7[i][j]);
```

You should use

```
fprintf(pFile,"%d,",X7[i][j]);
```

Use a comma AFTER the data instead of a TAB+space, since it is a comma-delimited-file. With this approach you will have a blank column at the end, but it should not be a big problem.

---

Instead of

```
printf("\n");
```

use

```
fprintf(pFile,"\n");
```

Comment: There were always two for loops, once was just not formatted as code above

Comment: Your alternative puts two commas between adjacent fields (`fprintf(pFile, ",%d,", X7[i][j]);`) which is wrong. It is easily arguable that you should prefix an output value with a comma except for the first value on each line.  There are many ways to achieve that.  My preferred one is `const char *pad = ""; for (…) { fprintf(pFile, "%s%d", X7[i][j]); pad = ","; } fprintf(pFile, "\n");`.

Comment: My bad again, it seems I should do nothing dangerous today - considering my (lack of) attention to details :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `\t` (tab) characters which will result in a tab-and-comma delimiter between each value (which I can see giving libreoffice or excel fits (is it a .csv or a tab-delimited file?)

Traditionally, you would output your *comma-separated-values* with a conditional to prevent placing a comma at the beginning of each row. Something like the following is all you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1940; i++) {                /* loop over rows */
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {             /* loop over columns */
        if (j > 0)                              /* if not 1st in row */
            fprintf (pFile, ",%d", ,X7[i][j]);  /* add "," before val */
        else
            fprintf (pFile, "%d", ,X7[i][j]);   /* no comma */
    }
    fputc ('\n', pFile);     /* add newline at end of each row */
}
```